# Pfsense: Inbound Load Balancing https with sticky connection

Tags: load-balancing, https, pfsense, sticky-sessions

first of all I'm very sorry for my English...

This is my scenario:

Internet

Firewall+LB: pfsense_1(Active) + pfsense_2(Passive) in CARP

Pool servers: 3 x nginx(PHP5+HTTP+HTTPS)

Pfsense 1 and 2 CARP configured with Virtual IP (pubblic). Nginx servers's ips are all private.

I want to load balance inbound HTTP and HTTPS connections between the 3 nginx web servers. An importat thing is that the HTTPS connections must be "sticky connections": in HTTPS connections, after login by username and password, I setup a php session and therefore when a client starts a HTTPS connection it will be always redirected to the same nginx server, until it disconnects itself, it closes the page/browser or after a timeout (30minutes?) without activity.
Is this possible whit the last release(2.0.1) of pfsense?

thank you very much...

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is install a more traditional load-balancing software such as [HAProxy](http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Haproxy_package)(it is a package in pfSense or can be a separate server).  There you should be able to configure sticky sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Your load balancer needs to handle SSL; otherwise it cannot read HTTP headers which it needs for sticky sessions.

I do not see any out-of-the-box solution for this. If you want this on the pfsense box, probably what I would do is install nginx from BSD Ports, and have that do the actual load balancing.

Comment: ok, but nginx is not one of the pfsense's packages...ho can I install it? fro BSD ports? I'm not expert of freeBSD, I have alway worked with linux...thank you